# How to select 10 columns but hide a column if all of its values in the rows are NULL

Tags: null, hide

```
SELECT
    p.id, 
    pol.description1, pol.DESCRIPTION2, pol.DESCRIPTION3, 
    pol.DESCRIPTION4, pol.DESCRIPTION5, pol.DESCRIPTION6, 
    pol.DESCRIPTION7, pol.DESCRIPTION8, pol.DESCRIPTION9, 
    pol.DESCRIPTION10, pol.DESCRIPTION11, pol.DESCRIPTION12, 
    pol.DESCRIPTION13, pol.DESCRIPTION14, pol.DESCRIPTION15  
FROM
    .table.
WHERE
    id = 1
JOIN ... On...
```

This returns 15 columns. and 200 rows.

- Column 1 has data in every row - ok
- Column 2 has data in most of the rows - OK
- ...
- Column 10 has no data in any of the rows - hide / don't return this column
- Column 11 is the same - no data in any rows - hide this one too
- and so on..

If I try not null, I end up loosing all rows as column 10 has no data in any of the rows... so hide everything :(

Comment: If you don't want to return a column from your `SELECT` - just don't specify it in the list of columns. There's really no other way to do this....